# Drupal #limit_validation_errors does not work

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I am constructing a form with Drupal FAPI and is a little bit complex one. What I want to do is to put a button and add some information when the user clicks it, so I need to skip validations with that button. I'm trying to use the #limit_validation_errors property but doesn't seem to work and is executing all validations.

I've noticed that when I put the element at the root level of the form tree it does work. This is what I have:

```
$form['application']['education']['add_education'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add',
    '#submit' => array('_education_submit'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);
```

The code above doesn't work, the code below works though:

```
$form['add_education'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add',
    '#submit' => array('_education_submit'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(),
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like Drupal is looking for the triggering_element using the value attribute to compare; as I have another button with the same value, the system is messing up the values and taking the other button as the clicked one.

To fix the code, I only have had to change the #value property of the button. It was working when I changed the position on the tree because in that case Drupal took the right button.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the example of using this property:

```
$form['add_education'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Add',
    '#submit' => array('submit_function'),
    '#limit_validation_errors' => array(array('_education_submit')),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Drupal 8, I had to switch from a `type="submit"` to `type="button"` in order to disable errors + use Ajax.

```
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

    // ...

    // Create Draft Button
    $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="send-emails-manual-send-by-role-wrapper">';
    $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';
    $form['actions']['save_draft'] = [
      '#type' => 'button',
      '#value' => $this->t('Save Draft'),
      '#name' => 'submit__save_draft', // TODO: Make constant
      '#limit_validation_errors' => [],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => [$this, 'ajaxSubmitForm'],
        'wrapper' => 'send-emails-manual-send-by-role-wrapper',
        'method' => 'replace',
        'effect' => 'fade',
      ],
    ];
    
    return $form;  
  }

  /**
   * Submit the form using ajax
   */
  public function ajaxSubmitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->submitForm($form, $form_state);
    return $form;
  }
```